mysql-connector-python self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs) crashes the application
I have issues with my PySide6 application. In the application I am using mysql-connector-python libary and trying to connect to our private Mysql server. I have noticed that on some computers, my application will run without any issues, while on other PC's it will crash with Process ended with exit code 3221225477.
I have run my application in debug mode where the application is crashing and narrowed down the issue. The issue lies very deep within mysql-connector-python.

In my mainwindow.py, I call:

        self.mysql_db = mysql_db(self)
        print("Mysql class object created")
        if self.mysql_db is not None:
            if (self.mysql_db.DB_start("OUR_DB") == 1):
                self.ui.MYSQL_status_edit.setText("Connected")
                self.ui.database_edit.setText("RND_Testing")
                self.ui.MYSQL_status_edit.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(60, 179, 113);")
            else:
                self.ui.MYSQL_status_edit.setText("Disabled")
                self.ui.MYSQL_status_edit.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 99, 71);")


In my mysql_db.DB_start, I call:

self.mydb mysql.connector.connect(host="server.hostname.lt",user="root",password="password",database=database,connection_timeout
   = timeout)```


mysql connect method returns CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs) in pooling.py
In CMySQLConnection class init method (connection_cext.py), it tried to do:

      if kwargs:
            try:
                self.connect(**kwargs)
            except Exception:
                self.close()
                raise


Inside self.connect(**kwargs) from CMySQLConnection class, it calls self._open_connection() in abstract.py
Inside _open_connection, it calls self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs) (connection_cext.py) which crashes my application.

I would appreciate if someone could provide some insights regarding this issue. Why would it work on some PC's and not work on other PC's?
Additionally, I have tried to confirm if the PC can reach the our MYSQL DB server and tried to run very simple MYSQL program :
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error



class mysql_db():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def DB_start(self,database, timeout=3):
        try:
            self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="our_server.hostname.lt",user="root",password="password",database=database,connection_timeout = timeout)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print(f"mydb failed: {err}")
            return 0
        print("Connected to DB OK")
        return 1

mysql_db = mysql_db()
mysql_db.DB_start("OUR_DB")

and it works without any issues. However, when I try to connect to my DB from within my PySide6 application, it crashes

You may have to raise this issue with whoever created PySice6. This seems to be some kind of a bug within a package.
